# MS Access - Combine varchar column with int column - ASP.net VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, type-conversion, alias

I'm using an oledb connection string to connect my asp.net code to an access db
I can't seem to convert combine the 3 fields -  `ProductID`(NUMBER) 
 `ProductCode`(TEXT), `ProdDescription`(TEXT)

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ProductID, (CAST(ProductID AS TEXT) + ' - ' 
                      + ProductCode + ' - ' + ProdDescription) AS [Prod] 
                      FROM [FG - End Product Codes] 
                      ORDER BY ProductCode;"
```

I've also tried

```
(CAST(ProductID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' - ' + ProductCode + ' - ' + ProdDescription) AS [Prod]
```

And

```
(CONVERT(ProductID, TEXT)) + ' - ' + ProductCode + ' - ' + ProdDescription) AS [Prod]
```

AND

```
(CAST(ProductID) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' - ' + ProductCode + ' - ' + ProdDescription) AS [Prod]
```

AND

```
(CAST([ProductID] AS TEXT) + ' - ' + [ProductCode] + ' - ' + [ProdDescription]) AS [Prod]
```

> Error msg: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException:
>   'IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).'
>
> error code : -2147467259

I seen the same error in another question but theirs seem to have some reserve keyword problem, If mine is the same, what is My reserved Keyword and where is it in my code?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you try to use T-SQL against Access which uses Access SQL. So, try this:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ProductID, ProductID & ' - ' & 
                  ProductCode & ' - ' & ProdDescription AS [Prod] 
                  FROM [FG - End Product Codes] 
                  ORDER BY ProductCode;"
```